# Weird behavior when declaring class property with semicolon

Tags: javascript, es6-class, ecmascript-next

```
class SomeClass {
  x: 5;
  y = 10;
}

const c = new SomeClass();
alert(c.x + ' : ' + c.y);
```

[image: Edit mqkw2zk94j]

Why is the code compilable but the value of `c.x` is undefined?

What is the effect of declaring a class property with `:`?

Comment: This is not ES6, and I don't believe the `x: 5;` is even a proposal of any sort either.

Comment: This is not a valid class declaration in js.

Comment: The `y = 10;` statement is part of [this Stage 3 Proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields).

Comment: It might be a type annotation in some language extension, but it's definitely not valid JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the `x: 5` part, although this is a valid javascript code, there is no much use for it.
This is a javascript [`label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) and it used (if any) mostly within loops context.

So to answer your questions:

> Why is the code compilable

Because technically this is a valid javascript code (yet not a valid `class` field).

> but the value of `c.x` is undefined

Because the `x` is a label and not a class field.

> What is the effect of declaring a class property with `:`

You get a label instead of a class field.

---

**Addendum**
Another common mistake, is this code of block:

```
class SomeClass {
  z = () => {
    x: 5;
  };
}
```

You would think that `z()` will return an object with an `x` key:

```
`{x:5}`
```

But actually you have a function with a label of `x` that just run an expression of `5`.

Just for completeness sake, the fix will be either to add an explicit return and another set of curly braces

```
() => {return {x: 5}}
```

Or just wrap the whole thing with parentheses

```
() => ({x: 5})
```

**Edit**
As a followup to the comments below:
Just to be clear, your code compiles on several environments that i tested as well as stack-snippets as can be seen below:

```js
class SomeClass {
  x: 5;
  y = 10;
}

const c = new SomeClass();
console.log(c.x + ' : ' + c.y);
```

Comment: Inside of a block (`{ … }`, looking like an object literal) it might be valid code, but no a label is definitely not valid as part of a `class` body.

Comment: @Bergi _"a label is definitely not valid as part of a class body"_ where did i say it was? i wrote: "_although this is a valid javascript code, there is no much use for it..._". this is valid __javascript__ code, hence babel won't complain about it (it will be ignored of course).

Comment: You said that it's valid code, but it clearly isn't. The `x: 5` part *of the class* is not valid code. That the token sequence "`x: 5`" can be a valid part of an object literal, a valid part of a string literal, or even a valid statement on its own, does not matter at all for the question. The code that the OP posted is not compilable.

Comment: I'm not trying to argue here but i like to be clear (and maybe learn from my mistakes). the OP asked: _"Why is the code compilable but the value of `c.x` is undefined?"_. You can't ignore the fact that the code is compile-able (you can check how [babel generates](https://babeljs.io/repl/) it with no errors as well). I still think it is valid code because there are no errors, is it a useful code? of course not.

Comment: It doesn't compile for me. Babel throws "*repl: Unexpected token (2:3)*" as well. What settings do you use?

Comment: Ah, it parses with the react preset. However, it's definitely not a label. I'll need to do some digging what particular plugin enables that.

Comment: @Bergi It's getting interesting, don't forget to ping us with your findings. I'm quite curious now :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165338/discussion-between-sagiv-b-g-and-bergi).

Comment: So it's a "valid" JS code that is pointless in this context. Compilers/linters should be able to identify the context and trigger an error instead of silently ignoring it...

Answer (score 0):

The code is not valid ES6.

You seem to be "compiling" with babel, and have inadvertently enabled the [flow](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-flow/) syntax extension (and also [class properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-class-properties/) for the second line). In flow, `x: 5` is a [class field type annotation](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/classes/). Of course, `5` as a type doesn't make sense, but apparently they allow pretty arbitrary expressions.

Comment: I'm not sure you are right here because if that was true, this code should compile: `class SomeClass {
  x: number = 5;
}` but unfortunately it doesn't.